# How to preview and then post multiple image back in mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I know I can use the following element to take **multiple** files at the same time

```
<input type="file" multiple id="Image" name="Image" size="40" />
```

and then in controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ViewResult Add(List< HttpPostedFileBase> Image = null)
 {
       ...
 }
```

but I want to add images individually or together then have preview of each **images** before posting. and I know there is some good solution like the following that **adding new image dosen't remove previous images**

[http://jsfiddle.net/2xES5/28/](http://jsfiddle.net/DXGTN/1/)

**The problem is**:

1. If the last time I've added images together only those images are
   posted back
2. If the last time I've added an image only that single
       image is posted back

I mean it depends how I added images at the last time?!

**My question is how can I add images individually or together then have preview of the images then post them back?**

It would be awesome if help me

Thanks

Comment: If you have `List<HttpPostedFileBase> Image` in your action, you can post one or more images, just to let you know

Comment: I know but I want to add as much as image I want then post them back like "http://jsfiddle.net/2xES5/28/ " that you can add as much as image you want in several times then post all the image back.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand.  I just submitted 4 images using the code you provided...?  How do you mean you want to post multiple images as many times as you want, you can do?

Comment: Ohhhh I think I know what you mean now.  You want to select multiple images multiple times and for them all to be posted?

Comment: Yes exactly that is what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In summary: Use multiple multiple file inputs.

Current jsfiddle:

- one multiple-file-input
- select files
- shows files
- select files again
- only latest files are uploaded

so after the file select, hide the multiple-file-input and add another one.

```
<div id='filecontainer'>
    <input type="file" class="dimmy" id="image-input" multiple />
</div>
<div class="preview-area"></div>
```

if you want the 'browse' to appear after the previous selection, then put preview-area first.

```
$(inputLocalFont).hide();
inputLocalFont = $('<input type="file" class="dimmy" multiple />')
    .appendTo("#filecontainer")
    .get(0);
inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change", previewImages, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9vzhbpgt/1/

I've used jquery to hide+add element then your original js to add the event listener.

Comment: The only problem is that you don't retain the `name` attribute on the additional file selectors on your JsFiddle.  If you did then it would work.

Comment: The original fiddle didn't post (as it's a jsfiddle).  There should only be one element with the same `id`.  As you used `id` and not `name` in the original fiddle, I removed `id` from the `appendTo()` as I didn't want to confuse the solution with code that tracked how many inputs had been added and incremented the `id`.  They can have the same `name` attribute and worth noting if that is needed at time of post.